# Is there Spring Core or Spring MVC (non SpringBoot) way of building DataSource object in Spring Framework programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am learning Spring Security.
In Spring MVC application (Spring Core) I am trying to get data source in SecurityConfiguration.
I saw examples when datasource can be built from application.properties or xml files. Whereas I want to do it programmatically.
Also I saw DataSourceBuilder, but it is from Spring Boot. Whereas I am trying not to use Spring Boot, but to use Spring Core, Spring MVC frameworks.

Another solution I see is to use JNDI naming with javax.naming.Context

Is it fine? Is JNDI way of accessing data sources is used nowadays in production applications?

Comment: DataSource is an interface. You need some specific impl. Hikari is what Spring Boot uses by default these days AFAIK. So instantiate a [HikariDataSource](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/2.6.3/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource.html#HikariDataSource--). You will need to add the dependency for it.

Comment: You should examine `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` in Spring Boot (at least to see how they do it), and no, production applications use Boot.

Comment: @Michael, thank you. I am trying not to use Spring Boot. I want to use only Spring Core, SpringMVC.

Comment: I believe you can, you just need to add the correct spring dependencies. Spring boot is essentially a fancy way of managing the required spring dependencies. So you  should be able to use the spring-core artifact, as an example. The trick is to find out which ones you need for your specific scenario and to get them on the class path. Not all production software uses spring boot. It can definitely be added independantly, try it and see what happens :)